# I'm trying to find 1 in the array and getting -1. help me with the code in rotated sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search, sortedlist

```
public class searchInRotatedSortedArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {3,4,5,6,7,0,1,2};
        int target = 1;
       
        int peak = peak_ele(arr);
        int ans = bs(arr, target, 0, peak);
        if (ans == -1) {
            ans = bs(arr, target, peak+1, arr.length-1);
        }
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
    
    
    
    static int peak_ele(int[] arr){
        int start=0;
        int end=arr.length-1;
        
        while(start<end){
            int mid=start+(end-start)/2;
            if(arr[mid]<arr[mid+1]){
                start=mid+1;
            }
            else if(arr[mid]>arr[mid+1]){
                end=mid;
            }
          
        }
        return end;
    }

    static int bs(int[] arr, int target, int start, int end) {
        
        while (start <= end) {
            int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
            if (arr[mid] == target) {
                return mid;
            }
            if (arr[mid] < target) {
                start = mid + 1;
            } else {
                end = mid - 1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    


}
```

I was expecting to get the index of 1 in the array but I'm getting -1. The second half of array to find the target is not working idk. Help me find the error in the code as I have tried many times but I just couldn't figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is wrong.You are finding the peak element and trying to do a binary search from start to end which will not work since the target could be anywhere in the array. If you are trying to search in a rotated array, try this

```
public static int search(int[] nums, int target) {
    int start = 0;
    int end = nums.length - 1;

    while (start <= end) {
        int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;

        if (nums[mid] == target) {
            return mid;
        }

        if (nums[start] <= nums[mid]) { // Left side is sorted
            if (target >= nums[start] && target < nums[mid]) {
                end = mid - 1;
            } else {
                start = mid + 1;
            }
        } else { // Right side is sorted
            if (target > nums[mid] && target <= nums[end]) {
                start = mid + 1;
            } else {
                end = mid - 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {3,4,5,6,7,0,1,2};
    int target = 1;
    int index = search(arr, target);
    System.out.println("Index of " + target + " is " + index);
}
```

Comment: what I'm trying to do is here finding the peak element and then search in the first half and if not found search in the second half as both the halves are sorted in ascending order so why I'm struggling to find element present at the second half.

Comment: well my finding peak element function is wrong